# SVN access denied when comparing revisions

Tags: xcode, svn

We're using an SVN repository. I am getting the error below when we try to compare a local unmodified file with the latest revision of the file in the repository. In other words, someone's checked in a change and if I update I will get their change but first I want to see what their change was. DOn't think it matters but we're using Xcode and using the menu item SCM -> Compare With -> Latest.

Error: 220001 (Item is not readable) Description: Unreadable path encountered; access denied

Any pointers where to look to fix this appreciated. I looked in the svnserve.conf which has the default settings. Nothing jumped out to me.

Also,

% svn log

returns "svn: Item is not readable".

Thanks,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 11):

You have bad configuration (or Subversion has a bug:)).

Anyway it can be fixed by changing in "svnserve.conf" file the line:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
```

Another solution to change only "authz" file the line:

```
[/]
* = r
```

That solution is given anonymous reads your repository that is not good. 
If you need to use only authorization repository than use the first solution. (was tested with svn 1.6.17, but think it does not depend from version)

Comment: Finally a solution that works and doesn't open the repo to public!  <3

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough rights to read every file changed in those revisions. Hence, Subversion considers the revisions "unreadable" for you. This is explained in the [authz_policy.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/authz_policy.txt) document.