# SVN blame - Network connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: linux, svn, phpstorm

I'm suddenly getting a weird error when I try to run `svn blame`

```
$ svn blame file.txt
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

This worked before and I haven't updated the version of SVN on my machine in a long time.  Currently using 1.6.11

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
compiled Jun 23 2012, 00:44:03
```

Incidentally, I can no longer do `svn diff` either.

```
$ svn diff -r PREV:HEAD file.txt 
svn: Unreadable path encountered; access denied
```

This also used to work.  The only thing that's changed in the last few years is I stopped using Zend Studio and started using PHPStorm (about two weeks ago).  Checking things like SVN history and running diffs in Zend Studio worked fine, and *seemingly* worked fine - **at first** - with PHPStorm.  At first I thought it was just a PHPStorm bug, but then I was running things manually with CLI and got the same messages.

`svn update` and `svn commit` still work..  What is going on?

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a valid and well-formatting question.  And the answer, _my_ answer _is_ indeed the correct solution.  This question could help others, so a downvote doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this when a different application gave a more meaningful error message.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517088/486233), I found that the problem was with `svnserve.conf`.

By adding this to my svnserve.conf file, the issue was resolved:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
```

Comment: And downvote here too?  Why?  The solution does in fact work.  And I asked this a year ago and I didn't exactly see anyone jumping in line to answer..